# In wordpress to mark required fields in Add New Post page

Tags: wordpress, validation

in WP 4.2 opening Add New Post page and without editing any fields, clicking on "Publish" button page is submitted and reopened, but no any of fields are marked with red background color as required.
How to make it? Seems, that is original behauvior of this page.
I want it to work like editor of categories, when in similar situation field name  is marked with red background color as required.

Also I added several fields to New Post page using register_post_type function and I aslo want to  marked with red background color as required. Which is the best way for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mandatory-fields/)

Answer (score 0):

You can call your jquery validation by your self using below code,

Add this code in theme's `functions.php`  and `custom.js`  in your theme `js` folder

```
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post-new.php', 'custom_admin_script', 11 );
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post.php', 'custom_admin_script', 11 );

    function custom_admin_script() {
        global $post_type;
        // Post type = "post" or "page" you can load script wheater it is post or page , if page then change 'post' to 'page' in below condition

        if( 'post' == $post_type )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-admin-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js' );
    }
```

**custom.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    if ($("#post").length > 0) {

        var frm = true;

        $("#publish").click(function () {

            var title = $("#title").val();
            var excerpt = $("#excerpt").val();

            // your custom field variable goes here 

            if (jQuery.trim(title) == "" || jQuery.trim(excerpt) == "") {
                frm = false;
            }

            if (frm == false) {
                $("#publish").prop('disabled', true);
            } else {
                $("#publish").prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help!

Plugin Mandatory Field is usefull, but seems it does not work with custom type, created with register_post_type function. 

I will try to edit it for my case...


Also a questions which are id and name values of RTF editor(CKEditor in my case as I have "CKEditor for WordPress" plugin installed ) to get its value as 


[code]$("#post_content").val(); ?


As for JS script in my case I do not need to disable "Publish button, I more need to stop submitting of page. If there is a way for this?

Comment: do you want to check post content area is empty? and you also want to know the `ID` of `post content` area where the editor is shown ?

Comment: also you must set the publish button disabled untill all fields are not empty, if you do not do this your validation is useless.

Comment: Yes, I wnat to know name and  ID of post content. I did not find it in firebug

Comment: CKEDITOR use `content` as name. so you will need `if ( CKEDITOR.instances.content.getData() == '' ){
    alert( 'There is no data available' );
}`